# How can I delete a php file inside a folder?

Tags: php

I have a php file inside a folder (`folder/abc.php`) and I would like clean up and delete the file after the fact that the certain task has been done and there is no need to keep that file inside that folder anymore.
What is the right function or code to delete that file?
Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to delete a file using PHP ?

Comment: Yes, by using PHP first then look at the other alternatives!

Comment: @callmejoejoe, check out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in this way:

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'folder/abc.php';
if (file_exists($path)) {    // Check if file exists in folder or not?
    unlink($path);
}
else{
    echo "File does not exists in the directory!";
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will be returned with the trailing directory separator, so there is a good chance this code will not word. Add a directory separator to the beginning of your static path: `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/folder/abc.php';`

Comment: Thank you @Finwe for pointing that out. I have updated that in my answer.

Comment: I've got kind of error while I use `if (file_exists($filename))` and I get the else  `echo "File does not exists in the directory!";` but by removing the whole if `file_exists` then the code  runs! means, only this works fine `$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'test/abc.php';
unlink($path);`

Comment: ok, @callmejoejoe, It was my answer initially but then I edited my answer and added the `if` condition. Otherwise I was first to answer this to your question.

Comment: By the was the mistake in `if` condition was the wrong variable. I had written `$filename` but it should be `$path`. I have updated my answer with that 
change. Now the code should work with `if` condition.

Comment: OK, you have to edit it again and remove `/` from `'/folder/abc.php'` to `'folder/abc.php'` because the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` will add a `/` at the end to the document-root !

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$filename = './test/abc.php';

if (file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "Deleting $filename";
    unlink($filename);
} else {
    echo "The file $filename does not exist";
}
?>
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php & http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Answer (score 1):

`unlink('your_file_path');` . Make sure your script have specific permission.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/test/abc.php';
unlink($path);
```